# What is the relationship between the field fixed by the decomposition group and the embeddings in the p-adic numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I am reviewing stuff about local fields and wanted to clear this relationship before going forward.

Let us first fix some notation. Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a finite galois extension of the rational numbers with Galois group $G$, $p$ a prime number, $D$ its decomposition group, $n$ the degree of the extension, $g$ the index of $D$ in the Galois group and $\mathbb{K}_{D}$ the field fixed by the decomposition group. We also call $f(x)$ the minimal polynomial of a primitive element $\mathbb{K}$.

It is clear to me that the index $g$ gives us the number of possible inequivalent extension of the p-adic absolute value to the field $\mathbb{K}$ and that each of these defines a different embedding of $\mathbb{K}_{D}$ in $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$. But some points are not yet clear to me.

1. Does this mean that the polynomial $f(x)$ splits in $g$ different irreducible factors of the same degree in $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$?
2. The field $\mathbb{K}_{D}$ may not be a galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. What does this mean? Does this imply that the irreducibles factor of $f(x)$ gives us inequivalent extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$? Do the converse hold, i.e., if the irreducibles factors of $f(x)$ gives us different extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ then $\mathbb{K}_{D}$ is not Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$?
3. If we take an extension $\mathbb{K}$ with **non-solvable** Galois group must we have that for any prime numbers $p$, the index $g$ is non-zero and hence all the primes splits?
4. If we take an extension $\mathbb{K}$ with **non-solvable and simple** Galois group does this mean that, by point 2, $f(x)$ is not irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ for any prime number $p$ and its irreducible factors gives us inequivalent extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ for all prime numbers $p$?

All these points make intuitive sense to me, yet I am unable to prove the first two. Also because I am not completely sure they are true. (Except for the third one which should follow from the fact that any extension of $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ is solvable.)

Comment: It's not a good idea to label a polynomial as $p(x)$ when you are *at the same time* using $p$ for a prime number.  Also, the prime $p$ usually does not have a single decomposition group $D$ in $G$: there is a decomposition group $D(\mathfrak p|p)$ for each prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ lying over $p$, and they are all conjugate to each other.  So your $D$ (as a function of $p$) is only defined up to conjugation in $G$, and likewise the field $K_D$ is only determined (as a function of $p$) up to isomorphism as a subfield of $K$.

Comment: Part 3 can be true even if $\mathbb K$ is solvable. If $p$ is unramified in $K$, then $D$ has to be a cyclic group (because it is isomorphic to a Galois group over $\mathbb F_p$). In particular, if $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb K/\mathbb Q$ is not cyclic, then $eg > 1$ for all $p$!

Comment: @KCd Thanks for making me notice both issues. I've fixed yesterday the notation. I was also quite un-careful while formulating the question. The answers, though, should not depend on the choice of the prime lying over $p$, right?

Comment: @Jabberwocky nothing depends on the choice of prime, since the extension is Galois.

Answer (score 1):

If $\Bbb{Q}[x]/(f)/\Bbb{Q}$ is Galois then factorize in irreducibles $f = \prod_{j=1}^g f_j\in \Bbb{Q}_p[x]$ each $\Bbb{Q}_p[x]/(f_j)/\Bbb{Q}_p$ is Galois and solvable and isomorphic to the splitting field of $f\in \Bbb{Q}_p[x]$. The subfield of $\Bbb{Q}[x]/(f)$ fixed by $Gal(\Bbb{Q}_p[x]/(f_j)/\Bbb{Q}_p) \subset Gal(\Bbb{Q}[x]/(f)/\Bbb{Q})$ is $\Bbb{Q}_p\cap \Bbb{Q}[x]/(f)$ where the embedding is the one sending $x+(f)$ to $x+(f_j)$.

Comment: So the answers should be: 
1) Yes, irreducible factors of the same degree.
2) They all give the same algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ no matter whether $\mathbb{K}_{D}$ is Galois or not.
3) yes, 4)no.
Then you also wrote the decomposition groups in that way since they depend on the choice of the prime lying over p. Everything right?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Also the $K_D$ (what I called $\Bbb{Q}_p\cap \Bbb{Q}[x]/(f)$) may be different for each $j$ (ie. each prime of $O_K$ above $p$) but they are all isomorphic over $\Bbb{Q}$ (because $Gal(\Bbb{Q}_p[x]/(f_j)/\Bbb{Q}_p)=\sigma_j Gal(\Bbb{Q}_p[x]/(f_1)/\Bbb{Q}_p) \sigma_j^{-1}$ where $\sigma_j\in Gal(\Bbb{Q}[x]/(f)/\Bbb{Q})$ sends a root of $f_1$ to a root of $f_j$)

Comment: Yes I had also understood that but thanks for highlighting it. These fields are then the same if the decomposition group(s) is (are) normal in the Galois group right?

Comment: Yes they are the same subfield of $K=\Bbb{Q}[x]/(f)$ iff the decomposition group (whence unique) is normal.